# How can I combine these two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, join, teradata

if I run these two queries individually, they both return results.  I'd like to combine them into a single query but im having some trouble.

```
SELECT LHI.PHYS_IT, LHI.LN_HLR_IFO_ID, LHI.LT_MD_DT, ORG.NAME, ORG.GR_DI, AGMT.AGMT_DI
FROM P_E_R_D.780VT LHI
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.750VT ORG ON (LHI.PT_DI = ORG.GR_DI)
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.710VT PGR ON LHI.PHYS_IT = PGR.PHYS_IT
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.500VT AGMT ON PGR.AGMT_DI = AGMT.AGMT_DI
WHERE AGMT.AGMT_DI IN (7492047204738);

SELECT LSE.CYC_DI, LSE.EAS_DI, LSE.LT_MD_DT, LSE.GR_EAS_DI, ORG.NAME, AGMT.AGMT_DI 
FROM P_E_R_D.130vt LSE
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.750VT ORG ON (LSE.PT_DI = ORG.GR_DI)
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.710VT PGR ON LSE.CYC_DI = PGR.PHYS_IT
INNER JOIN P_E_R_D.500VT AGMT ON PGR.AGMT_DI = AGMT.AGMT_DI
WHERE AGMT.AGMT_DI IN (7492047204738);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would allow other people to understand what YOU mean by "combine".

Comment: "Having some trouble" is a little vague. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want only one time to start the query you can put a `UNION ALL` between the two SELECT statments.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out.  I was attempting to combine the two queries using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I had placed it in the wrong order and it was erroring.